# Using an MVC Controller as proxy between the client and the Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to develop a single page application.

I have built a RESTful web service using ASP.NET Web API. I have implemented authentication using `OAuth 2.0` and `Bearer access tokens`.

This web service uses `memcached` and HTTP cache headers (`Cache-Control` and `ETag`) for caching the resources and responses.

Now, I really like ASP.NET MVC technology and maybe that love is making me use it when I shouldn't.

I'm thinking of builidng an MVC intermediate server between my JavaScript application and my Web service.

The MVC site would redirect (or delegate) its requests, to the Web Service.

I see many advantages using this approach:

- I can store my consumer key (used for authentication) in a secure location, as opposed to storing it in the JavaScript application directly.
- I can provide cookies to my JavaScript application, something that my REST web service does not support (because I think it ruins the whole "***stateless***" and "***Pure HTTP***" concept.
- It would be very easy for me to provide globalization (localization) to my views. I really like ASP.NET MVC globalization framework and I would not know how to add this feature if I plan to create a standalone site.
- I can encrypt my access token cookie, and decrypt it on the server, forcing my user to use my MVC proxy to access the web service, as he will not know his access token.

Having stated these advantages, would it be worth it to implement this?

Adding a proxy server will made me replicate the HTTP cache logic, and will also end up creating 2 requests (**Client -> MVC -> Web API**) instead of 1 (**Client -> Web API**).

What is the best approach?

Comment: Well, if you want to use sessions,etc why building REST service?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I don't think I want to use sessions, but I just see some advantages using them. Maybe they are not necessary or maybe I am missing some serious disadvantages, and I would like to know them before starting to build it. I would also accept experience tips, and what would you guys do in my situation

Comment: May be an XY problem. What are the reasons you feel you need a go-between? (Was it security of token [if so, why do you feel this is an issue]?; Why do you need cookies? etc.) You probably want to look at two APIs: one for front-end/UI that integrates security, and one that uses OAuth for 3rd party applications. (Both should just be exposed endpoints of the same service tier, btw)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've built a good RESTful web service, but need to address Auth and Globalization:

### Auth

Having this kind of proxy or support cookie authentication on the Web API will make you vulnerable to CSRF attacks, so you would also need to implement `Synchronizer Token Pattern` or [some other technique](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to prevent this. However you should only use this approach if you have no other options, but you have!

Assuming javascript application requires user to enter credentials, there are different ways to deal with auth for it:

- OAuth2 [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html)
- JSON Web Tokens - see accompanying [website](http://jwt.io) and a [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-31)

Both ways provide your JS app with an encrypted token that it should pass with each call to protected API. Your application would need to keep this token in a local storage and refresh it when token expires.

### Globalization

Even having most of the things on MVC side, eventually you would still require Web API to deliver translated content. So I'm not sure what are the requirements here, but generally speaking you should be able to get your translated resources on Web API the same way. See [here](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/web-api-localization/) for example.
For the HTML part - leave it to ASP.NET MVC, no need to put every label translation into API.

### Another points to consider

- **Performance** - ASP.NET MVC is good, but it's not a proxy solution and it's simply not intended to  build things like that
- **Do you really need an HTTP API?**
  Don't forget that transferring data over HTTP is another point of overhead, and it becomes especially useless if you proxy it with and MVC.
  At the end of the day - why would you build an API if you are hiding it from your own application?

My answer is: don't hide it - make full use of it!